# 401 Authorization Required with axis (from Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, axis, java

I am trying to access a https soap API.. I have the certificate from server and added to JRE cacerts (I can see the cert in the keystore). I am running a stand alone class and accessing SOAP service. I receive "401 Authorization Required" error. I am sure credentials are correct (verified case sensitive also).

I am wondering why its throwing the exception below:

```
- ERROR:return code:  401 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> 
<html><head> <title>401 Authorization Required</title> </head>
<body> <h1>Authorization Required</h1> <p>This server could not verify that you are  authorized to access the document requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.</p> 
</body>

</html> return code:  401 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>401 Authorization Required</title> </head>
<body> <h1>Authorization Required</h1> <p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.</p> </body></html>
```

NOTE: 1) username and password values are string. Does it need to be encrypted ( as I am  running client as java application). Although I tried to run as webapp (https), still causes same exception.
2) I can access SOAP endpoint via browser (with username and pwd) from system, so we can rule out any network related issue.

```
// Code snippet
PSPServiceLocator pfspLocator = new PSPServiceLocator();
pfspLocator.setPSPPortEndpointAddress(strNewAddress);
PSPPort pfspPort = pfspLocator.getPSPPort();    
PSPBindingStub pfspStub = (PSPBindingStub)pfspPort;

        // Force HTTP/1.0
        pfspStub._setProperty(
        org.apache.axis.MessageContext.HTTP_TRANSPORT_VERSION, org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_V10);
        // Configure Basic or Digest Authentication
        pfspStub.setUsername(userName);  // string value
        pfspStub.setPassword(password);  // string value
                int timeout = 1000;

        pfspStub.setTimeout(timeout);

        String strResultXML = pfspPort.cliRun(cmd);
```

Comment: 401 means server requires basic authentication, have you implemented credential details in your code? Better to show us some code sample where you set the credentials.

Comment: @yorkw: Thank you. updated post with code snippet and a note.

Comment: I know this is old as hell, but were you able to find the solution?